# Rails - serializer passing parametr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I use `active_model_serializers (0.9.2)`. I've been studying documention, stack and source code and still cant find some way to pass some parameter to serializer. The only one workaround is using `default scope`

```
def default_serializer_options
  {
    scope: some_param
  }
end
```

@options, options orserialization_options seems to be not working for me.

Comment: do u want to understand the concept of serialization? or what

Comment: I want to pass params from controller to serializer. Thats all I expect

Answer (score 0):

This is the link which will help you with it [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrpcuRCaAuA)
First create a serializer in the serializer folder.

```
class AttachmentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :attachment_url

    def attachment_url
        object.attachment_url
    end

end
```

Then in your controller you can do something like this

```
params.require(:model-name).permit( :attachment)
```

Comment: I use `render json: @books, each_serializer: BookSerializer` and I would like to pass addition param along with @books. Something like `render json: @books, name: 'John', each_serializer: BookSerializer` and then have access in to `title` in serializer to `name` but above doesnt work or I cant fetch this param then

Comment: do you know what I want now?

Comment: yes i know what you want know the link which i have provided will solve your problem if it doesn't tell me

Comment: well I could use scope but how to pass more than one param then?

Comment: still dont know how to pass params